# prove $(A \times B)^c = (A^c\times U)\cup(U\times B^c)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

got stuck proving that $(A \times B)^c = (A^c\times U)\cup(U\times B^c)$.

would appreciate your help, this is what I got so far:[image]

Comment: Please do not post large numbers of similar questions - you have asked seven questions that really do not differ by much. Instead, please see if the asnwers to one or two questions allow you to solve the other questions on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x,y)$ be an element of the left-hand side. Then $(x,y)\not\in A\times B$, and therefore $x\not \in A$, or $y\not\in B$  (or both).

Suppose $x\not\in A$. Then $x\in A^c$. It follows that $(x,y)\in A^c\times U$, and therefore $(x,y)$ is an element of the right-hand side.

A similar argument works if $y\not\in B$.

We leave it to you to show that every element of the right-hand side is an element of the left-hand side.

Comment: Nicolas can I tell that if $(a,b)\in(A^c \times B^c)$ then it's also in $(A^c \times B^c) \cup (U \times U)$ ?

Comment: Certainly, that is true. By the way, the convention here is that $U$ is some sort of "universal" set that contains the elements of $A$, of $B$, and possibly a lot more.

Comment: is it legal that I decided that if $(a,b)\in(A \times B)^c$ then $a\not\in A \land b\not\in B$. or I have to take also the possibilities when one of the doesn't happen

Comment: Not quite. If you look at my answer, you can see thar one conclude that $a\not\in A$ **or** $b\not\in B$.  In general one cannot conclude **and**.

Comment: what do you mean by 'one cannot conclude and'?

Comment: @Ami $(a,b)\in(A\times B)^c\iff (a\not\in A\ \lor\ b\not\in B)$.

Comment: @Ami: I mean that sometimes we have $(a,b)\not\in A\times B$, and $a\in A$ but $b\not\in B$. Or the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is what I got. would appreciate your attention if I made any mistakes.. thanks again.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}(A\times B)^c & = ((A\times \mathscr U)\cap (\mathscr U\times B))^c
\\ & = (A\times \mathscr U)^c\cup (\mathscr U\times B)^c
\\ & = (A^c\times \mathscr U)\cup (\mathscr U\times B^c)
\end{align}$

The first step, $(A\times B)= (A\times \mathscr U)\cap (\mathscr U\times B)$ is equivalent to $$\forall x\,\forall y\;\Big(\big(x\in A\,\wedge\, y\in B\big) \,\leftrightarrow\,\big( x\in A\cap \mathscr U\,\wedge\, y\in \mathscr U\cap B\big)\Big)$$

Which is fairly incontrovertable.

The second step is just deMorgan's Law for Set Complements

The last step hinges on $(A\times \mathscr U)^c = (A^c\times \mathscr U)$, and the symmetric claim.

This is equivalent to the claim that:  $\forall x\,\forall y\;\Big((x,y)\notin A\times \mathscr U \leftrightarrow (x,y)\in A^c\times \mathscr U\Big)$

Clearly this is the case, because is distills down to $\forall x\;(x\notin A \leftrightarrow x\in A^c)$ which is true by definition of set complement.